# Which field of W2 is compared with 130k threshold for NHCE/HCE classification?

Tags: united-states, 401k, form-w-2, hce

I understand that many companies use the 125k/130k/etc fixed threshold for classification of NHCE/HCE employees (whereas others use the 20% rule), which field of W2 is used to determine this?

For example, if you've contributed the full 19.5k to Pre-Tax 401k, does that reduce the income that's subject to the 130k cliff, or does it not?  How would one know if they're NHCE or HCE?